Capturing Log information in Mockito
I'm writing unit tests for a Java 8 project with testng and Mockito. I have a class that I'm testing that initializes the Logger without a constructor as such:
class MyTestClass {
    protected static final Logger LOG = LogManager.getLogger("MYLOGGER");
    
    public void someMethod(){
    LOG.info("This should be logged");    
    }
}

I know if the Logger is passed as an argument to the constructor, I can use a spy. But this is legacy code, and I can't add a constructor, unfortunately.
I'm wondering if it's possible to capture and verify the content of the log message in a test?
I would greatly appreciate any help with this. Thank you.

Depends on what logging framework you are using. I m going to assume Log4j2, but all good logging frameworks should allow you to specify a logging configuration that is used during tests, so one option is to swap to a log configuration that makes MYLOGGER log to somewhere it is easy for you to retrieve the log messages (i.e. a DB or a file).

Alternatively, you can programmatically create a custom appender that, before/upon/after appending, will capture the log event into a data structure of choice, and you can check this during your tests, but you will need to set it up before your tests and overwrite the existing MYLOGGER. i.e. https://www.baeldung.com/log4j2-custom-appender

Depending on the framework you can use MockedStatic for the logger instance and then create a Captor for the message. https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-mock-static-methods and https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-argumentcaptor
